# How to call a module in a block or give a module a block or put module form into a block?

Tags: 6, blocks

I have a module, and I would like its add form to be put into a block.  So my question is, how would you take a modules page (admin/build/mymodule/add) and give it a block?  So this module will now have its own block in the blocks admin page.  Do you do this by its url, by module, or by form id?

Comment: you want your module to have its own admin config page?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the $form_id and the function `drupal_get_form();`

You need to create a module and use `hook_block()`:

```
function mysecondmodule_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch($op) {
    case 'list':
      return array(array('info' => 'mymodule add block'));
    break;
    case 'view':
      if($delta == 0) {
        return array(
         'subject' => 'Mymodule Add',
         'content' => drupal_get_form('form-id');
        );
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysecondmodule_block($op='list',$delta=0,$edit=array()){
  switch($op) {
    case 'list':
       return array(array('info'=>'mymodule add block'));
       break;
    case'view';
       if($delta==0){
         return array(
          'subject'=>'Mymodule Add',
          'content'=> drupal_get_form('form-id');
           );
       }
```